# Count how many times a line appears based on part of text in a file with bash

Tags: bash

Lets say I have  a file:

```
Player spawned prop
'player' has left the server
'newplayer' has connected
'someone else' has connected
```

I want to count how many times the string 'has connected' appears, to get a final number of 2.

Comment: `part of text in a file with bash` - could you explain what did you mean  by `part of text`. You meant to say you don't want the whole text file eh?

Comment: `grep -c 'has connected' file` should do it unless you want to count of **occurrences** not count of lines

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 grep -o 'has connected' file| wc -l
```

should do it.

**grep** manpage says :

> -o, --only-matching
>  Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

**wc** manpage says :

> -l, --lines
>  print the newline counts

Answer (score 0):

If you do a search for "shell script" and "count string". You should find

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/count-total-number-of-occurrences-using-grep

will help you find a lot of ways you can do it.

Grep pipped to a word count is the easiest way, no need to complicate it with regex for a static string.